# /newsletter/manage/ and /sales/order/history/ blank

Tags: magento-1.9, customer-account

I have a site under development, and at some point the My Orders and Newsletter pages under My Account stopped working, and I cannot figure out why.

I turn on template hints, and it doesn't seem to be trying to load anything.
[image]

I'm at a loss for how to identify where the conflict is.  I've disabled any new modules but nothing helps.  Any advice on how to debug this?

Edit: PHP memory_limit is 512M, tried 1024M but didn't change anything.  I don't see anything in the apache log, or exception.log or system.log.

I installed Commerce Bug, and when I view Page Layout, I see that it doesn't have a 'content' area.  On an older staging server (that works), I see:

```
<reference name="content">
  <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="my.account.wrapper" translate="label">
    <label>My Account Wrapper</label>
    <action method="setElementClass"><value>my-account</value></action>
   </block>
</reference>
```

The site where the page is broken doesn't have this block.

Comment: check for error log in var/log/  folder.

Comment: More specifically,  your webserver error log file. Blank screen = hard PHP fatal error, which will be logged in your webserver error log file.

Comment: When I tail /usr/local/apache/logs/error_log, I don't see any new errors.  I cleared cache before checking.  I do see some errors about denied connection to local.xml, so I think it's the right log file.  I'm going to add some other clues to the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I didn't figure out the root cause, but came up with a solution anyway.  The theme's xml file set the left block of customer_account already, so I added in the content reference code above and now it works.  My best guess is there is a module overriding the content block of customer_account, so then re-declaring it in my theme overrides the override...